# Как сделать адаптивные изображения?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Подскажите вариант, как сделать адаптивные изображения?

Что хочется:

1. Под каждый breakpoint грузится свое изображение
2. Учитывается изображение для retina дисплеев
3. Изображения масштабируются

Comment: А что означает второй пункт? Если ретина, то вставлять изображение побольше в разрешении?

Comment: Да, именно так нужно

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для создания максимально адаптивных изображений подходит конструкция

```
<picture>
  <source media="(media-query-1)" sizes="(media-query-1.1) x, y" srcset="images/ordinary.jpg">
  <source media="(media-query-2)" sizes="(media-query-2.1) z, w" srcset="images/ordinary-2.jpg">
  <img src="images/ordinary.jpg">
</picture>
```

---

1. Допустим, вы хотите, чтобы на экранах до 400 пикселей было одно изображение, а на экранах больше другое. Делаем так:

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 400px)" srcset="images/ordinary.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 401px)" srcset="images/ordinary2.jpg">
  <img src="images/ordinary2.jpg">
</picture>
```

2. Также вы хотите, чтобы принималась в учет плотность пикселей. Тогда необходимо в атрибуте `srcset` указывать несколько путей изображений, через пробел писать `1x`, `2x` и, если необходимо, то и `3x`. `x` позволяет обратиться к *device-pixel-ratio*.

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 400px)" srcset="images/ordinary.jpg 1x, images/ordinary-retina.jpg 2x, images/ordinary-hd.jpg 3x">
  <source media="(min-width: 401px)" srcset="images/ordinary2.jpg 1x, images/ordinary2-retina.jpg 2x, images/ordinary2-hd.jpg 3x">
  <img src="images/ordinary2.jpg">
</picture>
```

3. Также вы хотите для разных брейкпоинтов разный *размер* изображения, тут придет на выручку атрибут `sizes`. У нас будет реализовываться следующий сценарий: 1) для экранов меньше 800 пикселей будет изображение `ordinary.jpg`, 1.1) для экранов 400 и меньше пикселей изображение будет иметь ширину `100vw`, в остальных случаях оно будет занимать `70vw`; 2) для экранов больше 800 пикселей `ordinary2.jpg`, 2.2) для экранов больше 1400 пикселей у него будет ширина `40vw`, в остальных случаях `50vw`.

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 800px)" sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, 50vw" srcset="images/ordinary.jpg 1x, images/ordinary-retina.jpg 2x, images/ordinary-hd.jpg 3x">
  <source media="(min-width: 801px)" sizes="(min-width: 1400px) 40vw, 50vw" srcset="images/ordinary2.jpg 1x, images/ordinary2-retina.jpg 2x, images/ordinary2-hd.jpg 3x">
  <img src="images/ordinary2.jpg">
</picture>
```

Comment: не совсем понял для чего size, почему просто не указать в css что минимальная ширина картинки равна 100% при разрешении меньше 540 допустим

Comment: Для того же, для чего нужны атрибуты `height` `width` у `<img>` — чтобы браузер изначально знал какой размер ему рендерить, даже пока картинка не загрузилась. Замечали, наверное, что на некоторых сайтах бывает так, что текст постоянно скачет по мере подгрузки картинок — этот тот случай, когда эти атрибуты не заполнены.

Comment: допустим есть 3 брейкпойинта, нужно сгенерировать 3 картинки для кажого брейкпоинта +  для каждого брейкпойнта для ретина дисплеев - это получается 6 картинок, а нельзя как то заиспользовать 3 картинки всего

Comment: например картинка 1280 px по ширине, есть копия  640 и 320, я могу использовать картинку 640 как ретину для разрешения 320

Comment: Можно. В `<source>` у `srcset` указывайте один адрес: `srcset="images/ordinary.jpg"`

Comment: Предлагаю вам немного поразмыслить, ответ на ваш конкретный вопрос есть в моём ответе :-)

Comment: и еще не понятно откуда взялся размер в 70vw

Comment: Эти размеры я просто придумал для иллюстрации.

Comment: так этого размера в коде я не вижу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56484/discussion-between-ruslik-and-sasha-omelchenko).

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться атрибутом [`srcset` (HTML5)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Атрибут может использоваться вместо `src` и позволяет задавать различные `URL` изображений. Значением атрибута является одна или несколько строк, разделенных запятой. В состав каждой строки входят:

1. URL файла с изображением
2. optionally, whitespace followed by one of:

   -- значение ширины `viewport` (им должно быть положительное целое число, за которым следует символ «`w`»). The width descriptor is divided by the source size given in the sizes attribute to calculate the effective pixel density.
     --
   значение плотности пикселей (положительное число, за которым следует символ «`x`»), по умолчанию равно `1x`.

Можно через медиазапрос + `:after` + `background-image`.